# Como subir archivo temporal a un servidor ftp?

Tags: java, ftp

Tengo la siguiente situación, quiero subir un archivo temporal a un servidor FTP, tengo el siguiente código:

```
public static void uploadFileFtp(String file,FTPClient client,String name) throws IOException {
        File files = File.createTempFile(name, ".txt");
        String[] lines = file.split("\n");
        int length = lines.length;
        BufferedWriter bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(files));
        for(int i=0;i<length;i++) {
            bw.write(lines[i]);
        }
        bw.close();
        InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(files.getName());
        boolean upload = client.storeFile(files.getName(), stream);
        if(upload)
            System.out.println("Hecho, numero de saltos de linea : "+length);
    }
```

File es una cadena que quiero escribir en mi archivo temporal(cosa que ya hace), despues intento obtener el nombre de ese archivo y subirlo a mi ftp, pero obtengo la siguiente excepción:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException: 103279143710072458372941584.txt (El sistema no puede encontrar el archivo especificado)
```

Me podrían ayudar a saber de que manera puedo obtener la ruta donde se guarda el temporal y pueda obtener dicho archivo.

Edit 1
Ya pude encontrar el archivo, debia encontrarlo de la siguiente manera:

```
InputStream stream = new FileInputStream(files.getAbsolutePath());
```

Ahora mi siguiente pregunta, hay forma de que yo pueda cambiarle el nombre a ese archivo temporal?

Gracias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> ¿Hay forma de cambiar el nombre a un archivo temporal utilizando el método `File.createTempFile(...)`?

No, no es posible ya que este método tiene algunas restricciones para evitar colisiones entre archivos con el mismo nombre.

Lo único que permite este método es añadir prefijo (`prefix`), un sufijo (`suffix`) y en caso de llamarlo con un tercer parámetro un directorio en donde guardar el archivo.

Por ejemplo:

```
tmpFile = File.createTempFile("tmp-", ".txt");
System.out.println("Ruta Archivo: " + tmpFile.getAbsolutePath());
// Ruta Archivo: X:\WINNT\TEMP\tmp-78345734.txt
```

Más información de este método puedes verla aquí:

[`createTempFile(String prefix, String suffix, File directory)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html#createTempFile-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.io.File-)

Por cierto, el número entre el *prefijo* y el *sufijo* se genera utilizando la clase [`SecureRandom`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/security/SecureRandom.html) que proporciona un generador de números aleatorios criptográficamente fuerte.

```
private static final SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();
static File generateFile(String prefix, String suffix, File dir)
    throws IOException
{
    long n = random.nextLong();
    if (n == Long.MIN_VALUE) {
        n = 0;      // corner case
    } else {
        n = Math.abs(n);
    }

    // Use only the file name from the supplied prefix
    prefix = (new File(prefix)).getName();

    String name = prefix + Long.toString(n) + suffix;
...
```

Por otra parte, si estás interesado en tratar de emular este comportamiento y tu controlar el como se crea el archivo temporal así como el nombre puedes optar por recuperar la propiedad del sistema `java.io.tmpdir` de las siguientes dos formas:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir"));
System.out.println(System.getenv("temp"));
// Puedes recibir algo como esto:
// X:\WINNT\TEMP\
// X:\WINNT\TEMP
```

Y seguido controlar la forma en que creas el archivo, en caso de que desees ver como realizar esto puedes optar por ver esta respuesta https://stackoverflow.com/a/28334688/6415698

Comment: Muchas gracias.